# Alternativa para Sendkeys no VB.net Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, windows

Alguém sabe de alguma maneira alternativa de se usar o Sendkeys no Windows 10? Tenho um programa que funciona perfeitamente no Windows 7, mas não funciona no 10 porque aparentemente Microsoft desabilitou o uso do Sendkeys nele.

O programa fica rodando na frente de qualquer outro e tem vários botões. Cada botão, quando clicado, executa o seguinte código:

```
    SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}")
    SendKeys.Send("ŷ")
```

A primeira linha é para dar alt+tab e trocar o foco para o último programa usado e a segunda é para enviar, na janela agora em foco, uma determinada string (no caso, "ŷ". Os outros botões fazem o mesmo, diferindo apenas na string enviada.

Alguém sabe de alguma outra maneira que isso pode ser feito no Windows 10? Obrigado!

Comment: net-core ou net-framework?

Comment: É net-framework

Comment: com msbuild ou com vs-studio ou com dotnet (linha de comando)? Está usando o UAC no aplicativo?

Comment: Tô usando o vs-studio. Provavelmente está com UAC, testei em um PC recém formatado.

Comment: O que UAC tem haver com PC formatado ou não? UAC é outra coisa.... UAC tem haver com permissão administrativa.

Comment: Falei que é formatado para que você saiba que está com as configurações padrão. Você sabe de alguma alternativa?

Comment: UAC não tem nada haver com configurações do sistema, tem haver com o modo que o aplicativo requer para iniciar.

Comment: Então não sei. Como verifico isso?

Comment: Verificar? Como assim, o app não é seu? Você não sabe o que vc mesmo escreveu nele? Se você o criou então você escreveu a parte do UAC, se você não sabe o que é isto e não escreveu nada relativo e o programa não requer adm então você não fez nada relacionado a isto. A resposta sensata, seria "não sei o que é isto", o que provavelmente já resumiria que vocÊ não programou esta parte, então eu lhe ajudaria com isto.

Comment: Eu escrevi ele há anos e faz muito tempo que não mexo com programação. Não lembro de ter configurado nada em relação a isso.

Comment: Não é questão de "configurar" é questão de olhar e verificar os detalhes, se não sabia o que era UAC era mais fácil ter dito, afinal sua perguntas esta desprovidas de detalhes minimos e estou tentando lhe ajudar a você se ajudar, porque não sou capaz de advinhar o que vocÊ fez, estou dispondo do meu tempo pra tentar lhe ajudar, um pouco de calma e sinceridade e até dizer, "desculpe não sei o que é isto", ajudaria.

Comment: De boa, mano. Não sei o que é isso.

Comment: Otimo, então não configurou. Na pasta do teu projeto tem um arquivo com a extensão `.manifest`?

Comment: Sim, tem um .vshost.exe.manifest.

Comment: Talvez tenha gerado sozinho, não tem nenhum com o mesmo nome do teu projeto? Ou app.manifest?

Comment: Com o exato mesmo nome, não. Mas o projeto tá como WindowsApplication1.exe e tem um WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe.manifest. Não tem nenhum app.manifest.

Comment: Ok, não tenho certeza se é isto, ou se é de uma versão antiga, faça o seguinte, no build do teu app gerado clica com o direito e seleciona iniciar como administrador e veja se o sendkeys funciona ... creio que possa ser isto pq na do MSDN não tem nada falando sobre compatibilidade do win10 com o sendkeys, então não sei se a informação que obteve sobre o assunto é verdadeira.

Comment: Na verdade, eu fiz uns testes aqui e vi que o sendkeys ainda tá funcionando, porque ele continuava dando alt tab, só não enviava a outra tecla. Aí eu coloquei um sleep(200) entre o alt tab e o envio da string e está funcionando perfeiramente. Parece que o tempo de mudança entre as janelas é maior, aí não dava tempo de os dois comandos serem enviados a tempo.

Comment: É bem provavel mesmo que tenha sido alguma mudança na renderização das janelas do Win10.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela disposição!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema colocando um delay entre um comando e outro.

```
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
SendKeys.Send("ŷ")
```